# falha no reconhecimento da seed do random_state do split LinearSVC #python

Tags: python, random, machine-learning, seeders

seed do random_state não está funcionando, sempre que eu rodo no jupyter, vem com uma precisão diferente.. alguém pode me indicar o erro?agradeço desde já :D

```
# estimador de aprovaçao baseado nas notas das matérias
# o número nas notas variam de 0 a 100
# 1 significa aprovado e 0 reprovado 
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dataset = pd.read_csv('Student.csv')
#valores não preenchidos serão tratados como nota 0, pois o aluno não compareceu a prova
dataset.dropna()
treinoX, testeX, treinoY, testeY = train_test_split(dataset.drop('Result', axis = 1),dataset['Result'].to_frame(),test_size = 0.25,random_state = 0)
estimador = LinearSVC()
estimador.fit(treinoX, treinoY)
previsao = estimador.predict(testeX)
precisao = print('precisão de {}%'.format(accuracy_score(testeY,previsao)*100))
precisao
x = input('defina a nota de Física:')
y = input('defina a nota de Matemática:')
z = input('defina a nota de Química:')
k = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x,y,z]).reshape(1,-1))
teste_previsao = estimador.predict(k)
if teste_previsao[0] == 1:
    print('parabéns, você foi aprovado!')
elif teste_previsao[0] == 0:
    print('você não foi aprovado,desculpe :/')
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema com um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz a seguinte alteração no seu código:

```
...
dataset.dropna()

X = dataset.drop('Result', axix=1, inplace=True).values

Y = dataset['Result'].values

treinoX, testeX, treinoY, testeY = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
...
```

Separei os parâmetros da `train_test_split` para facilitar, acrescentei o `inplace=True` dentro do `drop()` e transformei as variáveis `X`e `Y` adicionando o `.values` ao final de cada um deles. O `sklearn` só consegue fazer avaliações corretas quando você insere dados como `numpy.array`.

Um pequeno detalhe: mudei o valor do `random_state` para um valor maior que 0, não sei se isso tem efeito ou não.

Espero que resolva seu problema! Qualquer coisa podemos discutir aqui nos comentários!

Comment: obrigado! 2 duvidas: sempre que eu colocar .values em um dataframe, ele se tornará um array de numpy? eu também posso fazer isso com Series?você acha que o problema da seed era exclusivamente  por causa da formatação que não estava em array?

Comment: eu fiz a alteração recomendada, mas a seed continua com problema, sempre dá um accuracy diferente

Comment: Respondendo às suas perguntas: 1 - Sim. Se usar o `.values` em um dataframe ele sempre retornará um array do numpy. 2 - Sim, você pode fazer com Series também. 3 - Não creio que o problema seja com Series x array numpy. Teste isso hoje...

Tenta fazer o seguinte: define o parâmetro `random_state` quando você for criar o modelo, desta forma: `estimador = LinearSVC(random_state=50)` e veja se sua acurácia continua variando.

Comment: acredito que o problema era o inplace = False